# how to getting scrollbar width on macOS when I setting 'Show scroll bars: When scrolling'

Tags: javascript, html, css, macos-sierra

When I set `Show scroll bars: When scrolling` from `System Preferences -> General`，I can't get the scrollbar `width` in any browsers.

The scrollbar is in a floating state, so I get

```
div.offsetHeight - div.clientHeight = 0
```

I don't know if there are any options to solve this problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @rjdkolb thanks for your help!

Comment: Which browser are you using ? Chrome, Safari ?

Comment: Chrome, Safari and Firefox

Comment: I am running into the same issue, were you able to figure out a way to get the scrollbar width.

Comment: @AshD sorry, I did not found good way. I solved it with another idea.